# Mocked MailChimp class methods should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times- test fails

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock the `post()` and `success()` methods of a `MailChip` class for my test, however I'm getting:

> Method post('lists/audienceId/members', ['email_address' => 'fake@email.com', 'status' => 'subscribed']) from Mockery_2_DrewM_MailChimp_MailChimp should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

`MailChimp`'s constructor expects an api key, so for testing purposes I pass in a fake:

##### `AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
public function bindClasses()
{
    $this->app->bind(MailChimp::class, function ($app) {
        if (app()->environment('testing')) {
            return new MailChimp('test-key');
        }
        $site = request('channel', 'default-channel');
        $keys = config("services.mailchimp");
        return new MailChimp($keys[$site]);
    });
}
```

Then in `SubscribeAction`, I'm calling the `post()` and `success()` methods on the `MailChimp` class:

##### `SubscribeAction.php`

```php
class SubscribeAction
{
    private MailChimp $mailChimp;

    public function __construct(MailChimp $mailChimp)
    {
        $this->mailChimp = $mailChimp;
    }

    public function subscribe(string $site, string $email, bool $skipDoubleOptIn = false): array
    {
        $this->validate($site, $email, $skipDoubleOptIn);

        $status = ($skipDoubleOptIn) ? 'subscribed' : 'pending';

        try {

            $mailChimpResponse = $this->getMailChimpResponse(
                site: $site,
                email: $email,
                status: $status
            );

            $rsp = $this->transformResponse($mailChimpResponse);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $rsp = [
                'status' => 400,
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ];
        }

        return $rsp;
    }

    public function validate($site, $email, $skipDoubleOptIn): void
    {
        if (! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new ValidationException('Email address is not valid.');
        }
        if (! in_array($site, ['site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site4'])) {
            throw new ValidationException('The channel is not valid.');
        }
        if (! is_bool($skipDoubleOptIn)) {
            throw new ValidationException('skipDoubleOptIn must be a boolean.');
        }
    }

    public function getMailChimpResponse(string $site, string $email, string $status): bool|array
    {
        return $this->mailChimp->post(
            'lists/'.config('services.mailchimp.'.$site.'.audienceId').'/members',
            [
                'email_address' => $email,
                'status' => $status,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function transformResponse($mailChimpResponse): array
    {
        if ($this->mailChimp->success()) {

            return [
                'status' => 200,
                'message' => 'You have successfully subscribed to the newsletter!',
                'response' => $mailChimpResponse,
            ];

        } else {

            $rsp["status"] = 400;

            if ($mailChimpResponse['title'] === 'Member Exists') {
                $rsp["message"] = 'You are already signed up to our newsletter!';
            } else {
                $rsp["message"] = "There was a problem signing up to the newsletter. Please check your email address, and try again.";
            }

            return $rsp;

        }
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```php
/** @test */
public function test()
{
    // arrange
    $site = 'site1';
    $email = 'fake@email.com';
    $status = 'subscribed';

    $this->mock(MailChimp::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($site, $email, $status) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('post')
            ->once()
            ->with(
                'lists/'.config('services.mailchimp.'.$site.'.audienceId').'/members',
                [
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status' => $status,
                ]
            );
    });
    $this->mock(MailChimp::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('success')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);
    });

    $subscribeAction = resolve(SubscribeAction::class);

    // act
    $subscribeAction->subscribe(
        site: 'site1',
        email: 'fake@email.com',
        skipDoubleOptIn: true
    );
}
```

However it fails, as apparently neither `post()` nor `success()` are actually called.

If I `dd($this->mailChimp)` inside my `SubscribeAction`, I get:

```php
^ DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp^ {#3668
  -api_key: "test-key"
  -api_endpoint: "https://key.api.mailchimp.com/3.0"
  +verify_ssl: true
  -request_successful: false
  -last_error: ""
  -last_response: array:2 [
    "headers" => null
    "body" => null
  ]
  -last_request: []
}
```

So it looks like good to me... any ideas?

Comment: I have added my answer but could you share this info here: looks like your Mock is not being used, could update your question and share how is `bindClass` being used (where is it being called)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if it is using your mock, but you can improve the test a lot:

```php
/** @test */
public function test()
{
    // Arrange
    $site = 'randomString';
    $email = 'fake@email.com';
    $status = 'subscribed';

    config(["services.mailchimp.$site.audienceId" => $audienceId = 'someValue']);

    $this->mock(MailChimp::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($audienceId, $email, $status) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('post')
            ->once()
            ->with(
                "lists/$audienceId/members',
                [
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status' => $status,
                ]
            );

        $mock->shouldReceive('success')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);
    });

    // Act
    resolve(SubscribeAction::class)
        ->subscribe(
            site: 'site1',
            email: 'fake@email.com',
            skipDoubleOptIn: true
        );

    // You are missing the assertions
}
```

Then, your `AppServiceProvider` binding should be like this:

```php
public function bindClasses()
{
    $this->app->bind(MailChimp::class, function ($app) {
        $site = request('channel', 'default-channel');
        $keys = config('services.mailchimp');
        return new MailChimp($keys[$site]);
    });
}
```

And just update your `phpunit.xml` to have a new entry inside `<php>`:

```xml
<env name="YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE" value="test-key"/>
```

See that I have used `YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`, it should match whatever environment variable you are using for `config('services.mailchimp')`. The idea is to use environment variables, not ask the code if it is running a test or not.